# Special Azure User Defined Route - How should I do?

Tags: linux, azure, routes, centos, azure-virtual-network

I am writing to ask your help regarding a Microsoft <3 Linux related routing topic.

I have 2 Azure subscriptions and there are vnet-to-vnet peering connection between them. The 1st subscription contains some management servers such as jump server and DNS. The 2nd subscription contains the business related servers on separated way. (I mean the VMs are available only from the jump  server from 1st subscription) All of my servers are Linux servers and all of them have 2 NICs.

The required traffic is the following: 
**SSH has to work from Jump server eth1 to business servers eth1.**

Subnets:

- 1st subscription:
  - eth0: 172.10.0.0/24
  - eth1: 172.10.1.0/24
- 2nd subscription:
  - eth0: 10.99.0.0/24
  - eth1: 10.99.1.0/24

If I put the following line to route-eth1 on all VMs on 2nd subscription everything works fine:
**172.10.1.0/24 via 10.99.1.1 dev eth1**

**How can I implement this in Azure with user defined routes (UDR)?**

If I create the following route in Azure it does not work:
[Here is a screenshot about the route rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2qV3.png)

Thank you for your help in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the next hop address is invalid on your route table in Azure. 10.99.1.1 cannot be a virtual appliance as mentioned in the screenshot,that's a managed IP by Azure based on your subnet sizing list.

Comment: Yeah... I know what the issue is. I do not know the solution. Is it possible you provide a suggestion and not only point at root cause? Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I think you are look for BGP and VPN Gateway.

If you want to use jump server to login 2nd server from your local server, we can use BGP and VPN Gateway like this:

[image]

Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-bgp-resource-manager-ps).